# The use of private keyword in Swift and their use in protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, model, protocols

I'm building an iOS app where i want to make a protocol (Which by my understanding is the equivalent of java interfaces) for my model, to use for Unit Testing purposes.

In Java you typically want to encapsulate your values in a model and make them accessible through getters and setters only.

How can i ensure this encapsulation in Swift with protocols, where i can't use the private keyword for properties.

My model is setup something like this:

```
class model { 
    private var property: Int = 5

    func getProperty() -> Int {
        return property
    }

    func setProperty(newValue: Int) {
        self.property = newValue
    }
}
```

And i want my protocol to look something like this:

```
protocol modelProtocol { 

    private var property: Int { get set }
}
```

My problem is that i can't declare my properties private, is this just a thing in Swifts access control (I've read they have private, internal and public) that you don't use private properties that much or is there an equivalent to Java's way of handling interfaces and private variables?

(Note: I'm using Xcode 7 and swift 2.0 if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can have private properties and public Getters and Setters with Swift code, as the getters and setters cannot have a *higher* access control than the property. For unit testing purposes you can access any internal entity using the @testable attribute as shown in the documentation below.

> Access Levels for Unit Test Targets
>
> When you write an app with a unit test target, the code in your app needs to be made available to that module in order to be tested. By default, only entities marked as public are accessible to other modules. However, a unit test target can access any internal entity, if you mark the import declaration for a product module with the @testable attribute and compile that product module with testing enabled.

I do not think you would be able to declare private properties within a protocol, you may need to use a base class instead with internal properties and extend that class. I am still fairly new to protocols myself, but I believe they are mainly used to ensure code conforms to that protocol as in... it provides that functionality or those methods.

References Used:

[Swift Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3)

[Swift Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

[Swift unit testing access](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - very nice and descriptive +1 ! :)

But from my experiences from Java subclassing in my case would be a "no no", since I want to use a Strategy pattern to modify my model in different ways for testing, so I want to have a protocol, but also encapsulated properties, but seems like it's not that easy or even possible in Swift. *sadface*